# Android kill previous activities without a new intent

Tags: android, animation

I have 2 activities and I have a transition animation between the 2.
After going from activity 1 to activity 2 I want to remove activity 1 from the stack

I can't use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK because that causes the first activity to be killed before the animation is done and causes weird animations.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just use finish() above the animation line.

Comment: animation is on the second activity, calling finish will kill the second activity and it remains on the first activity

Answer (score 0):

You can register a `BroadcastReceiver` in Activity 1, when everything in Activity 2 is done, just send an event to Activity 1

Activity 2:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("FINISH_ACTIVITY_1");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Activity 1:

```
// Register receiver
mReceiver = new MyReceiver();
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();            
intentFilter.addAction("FINISH_ACTIVITY_1");  
this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);

// Nested receiver
private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // Do something
        finish(); 
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This solution doesn't work either, after calling finish it shows the first activity and then it kills it with animation

Answer (score 0):

Can acheive this by,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish(); //finish will clear the first ativity from stack
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.exit_anim, R.anim.enter_anim);
```

Comment: i think from your question u tried with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK. Instead try it with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. There is difference between FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK and FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to test this concept but the answer by Liar looks to be perfect.

Just change the word finish() in Activity 1 to finishAffinity()